# multiple uiimageviews from for loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, for-loop, uiimageview

I am writing a game in which a Uiimageview needs to be 'spawned,' if you will. every time the character hits the end box. Everything else is working except that. Could someone check my code and see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

```
for (int i = 1; i <= level; i++) {
        int xPos = rand() % 316;
        int yPos = rand() % 450;
        UIImageView *mine = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, 10, 10)];
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not adding the views that you create in a loop as subviews to your main view. That's why they do not become visible.

As a side note, I think you would be better off using `CALayer` objects instead of `UIImageView`: they are lighter-weight, and require about the same amount of work.

Comment: @Jeeter more like `[self.view addSubview: mine];`

Comment: @Jeeter Do not forget [mine release]; after [self.view addSubview: mine];. If you don't do it - it cause memory leak.

Comment: The image views are appearing, but the problem is that they will not respond to any other procedure other than background color when initialized. What should I do?

Comment: @Jeeter You may need to post some more of your code to see what is going on. Did you decide to stay with `UIImageView`, or took the `CALayer` approach? You may want to post this as a separate question, say,  "Dynamically added views (layers) do not respond to methods other than changing color", to benefit from other people taking a look. Since unanswered questions get a lot more attention on Stack Overflow than answered ones, you may get a good answer much faster.